# Schengen Visa for germany Refusal Reason #8. Should I Appeal or wait to reapply after 3 months

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

I have applied for Schengen Visa for Germany in Abu Dhabi on 06/09/2015 for 10 days and the Embassy Refused my application on 22/09/2015. Beacuse of reason no 8.

It was mentioned in German Language (Die vorgelegten informationen uber den zweck und die bedingungen des beabsichtigten Aufenthalts waren nicht glaubhaft) and also in English (the embassy does not hold that you have convinced it that you are going to Germnay for the purpose stated in your application)

Now What is the process, what should I do in this case. Is it good to wait for three months and reapply or it will be better to appeal.

Comment: In any event, the answer to your question depends on the specifics of your case, which are notably absent.  If @GayotFow's answer to his question, linked above, does not address any facts specific to your case, please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Refused 8 times?  I would say you're more likely to get refused on general principle now. :)

Comment: The English isn't a translation of the German.  The German is the 'official' reason

Comment: I have transelated the German language in english from Google.

Comment: (In German) Die vorgelegten informationen uber den zweck und die bedingungen des beabsichtigten Aufenthalts waren nicht glaubhaft
(And the Translation in English) The information provided about the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable

Comment: It isn't refused 8 times. the refusal reason no 8 was marked by Embassy

Comment: @ZahidAkhtar you should determine if you can develop a body of evidence that is more reliable, or if you can improve the reliability of your existing evidence (with corroborating evidence, perhaps) then you should probably submit a new application.  We can't speak more specifically to your evidence because we do not know what it is, nor do we know the purpose and conditions of your intended stay.

Comment: Thanks @Phoog. Actually I am not getting you point.

Comment: @phoog I had my my hotel and air ticket booking on 15th of October and returning on 24th of October

Comment: @ZahidAkhtar my point is that they said your evidence was not reliable (though I would think that *glaubhaft* is better translated as *credible*).  You are therefore more likely to succeed if you can provide better evidence.  A plane ticket does not prove you will return because it does not prove that you will actually go to the airport and board the flight.  Convincing evidence that you will leave is usually evidence demonstrating ties to your home country: job, school, etc. You may need to address the question of purpose, too, since they mentioned that in English, if not in German.

Comment: @phoog we were two Pakistani friends. we both have applied separately with different dates and we both have just booked flight reservation and hotel booking online according to our travel dates. but my friend got the visa and I refused.

Comment: @ZahidAkhtar that could happen for any of a number of reasons. Did you ask your friend about the evidence submitted to justify the purpose of the visit or to demonstrate intention to leave the country?

Comment: @phoog I am going to appeal against their decision in this case what I have to do